# How to get refund information for a Windows Store app via API

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, microsoft-partnercenter-java

We are publishing multiple games in the Windows Store and are looking to automate refund handling in an external server. Is there any web API that allows us to fetch all refunds for a specific app and time frame (e.g. all refunds for app X in the last 2 weeks)?

We saw that there's ways of doing this directly from within the app for the active user, but in our case it should be done on a backend system and by app, not by user.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the document for [Microsoft Store services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/using-windows-store-services). But currently, there is no store service API that could do this by a server or the app. The Store service API could [access analytics data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/access-analytics-data-using-windows-store-services) in the partner center but no data for refund.

Comment: Please submit a feature request about feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.